# How to find knockoutjs bug in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer, knockout.js

I have a knockoutjs 2.1.0 view model that I have developed and works with both Firefox and Chrome but not IE 8 or 9. When I open up the developer view in IE I do not get any error messages in the console but the view never gets bound. I have another app that uses Knockout just fine in both IE, Chrome, & FF. I'm looking for suggestions on how to determine where the error is.

**Solution:**
The solution was the following line was

```
<script type="application/javascript">
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Chrome & FF didn't care but IE didn't like it.

Comment: IE doesn't save the error messages until you open the console. Try refreshing the page with the console open.

Comment: If you want more help with this, you should post the code somewhere. E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try debugging it. Put a breakpoint at `ko.applyBindings`, start debugging, and step trough the code. If there are any exceptions, you should get notified. If there are no exceptions, you could try to find where the execution path differs from the other browsers.

If no error message is showing, and you can't find it with debugging, try scaling down your view and model. One piece at the time, until it starts working.

When you find one piece that breaks on IE, try isolating it by removing  everything else. If there would be multiple pieces that is required for it to break, you might need to continue removing pieces one piece at the time.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem was that IE8 would just hang, so it to figure out what was going on at all.